# Knockout.js how do I build up a string from a binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am creating a list of links using a knockout binding:

The Javascript and view model looks like this:

```
$(function () {
   var adminViewModel = function()
   {
       var self = this;
       self.leftItems = ko.observable([ { Name: "Item1", Id: 0 }]);
       self.getChildren = function (id, list) {
           var url ="@Url.Content("~/api/Test/GetChildren/")" + id;
           $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
              list(data);
           });
        };
    }
    var Admin3App = window.Admin3App = window.Admin3App || {};

    Admin3App.viewModel = new adminViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(Admin3App.viewModel);

    function getLeftChildren(id)
    {
        Admin3App.viewModel.getChildren(id, Admin3App.viewModel.leftItems);
    }
    getLeftChildren(0);

}
```

(EDIT: the init of the `ko.observable` was missing an Id (even though this did not cause an error, added it)

How this works is the view model will load a bunch of items that has no parent (id 0).
For the sake of simplicity I only included the left version. But the page has a list of items on the left and right so there is a function for each.

The left items is populated to view model left items and displayed as below. But each item is a link and once clicked via javascript will refresh the items based on the parent Id. (Much like browsing a folder viewer in explorer).

But i cannot figure out how to declare the binding in knockout to build up the url. I know this is probably rediculously easy and I am just missing it.

here is the html I have attempted amongst others

```
<div class="leftView">
    <div data-bind="foreach: leftItems">
        <a data-bind="text: Name, attr : { href:'javascript:getLeftChildren(' + Id + ')' }"></a><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

(EDIT: missed a single quote, but got the same error anyway)
But I keep getting a binding error

Comment: I would suggest refactoring your code: Add "getLeftChildren" to the view model (as it provides functionality related to the view, it belongs there) and use the "click" binding.

Comment: Where does your Id come from (used in the data-bind expression)?

Comment: For the example i added the object and it was missing the Id, but my running code does not have any item in the initialization of the array, but my returned objects from the Json has the Id, im correcting the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

1) leftItems should ideally be an observableArray

2) The initial object you push into leftItems does not have an Id property

Here is a JSfiddle that corrects a few things and demonstrates loading an initial set of data and then calling again to load different data.  I've also moved the outside JavaScript call inside the viewModel and switched to using a click handler to pass refresh the data (note that a click binding will automatically send the data item into the event handler as the first parameter, so you have access to the id you need for creating your URL).

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/xTHFg/

Comment: Point 1) Correct, I missed it for the example (this was not the cause of the error though) I corrected my question and added it. My binding was wrong period, I thought for such a thing just to put it on the viewModel, as a function or ko.computed or something and then bind directly like this attr : { href: refreshUrl }. But using click is more elegant and your example works and now mine is working perfectly too, thanks